# Google Maps Javascript and working with Polygons crossing +/-180 meridian

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When working with polygons on google maps, there can be cases where a polygon will cross the map overlap. For example, when going to the right edge of the map, and placing points to create a box, with the left points on the right edge of the map, and the right points on the left edge of the repetition of the map (as the map can pan infinitely horizontally).

That said, I would see points close to the +180 and -180 extremes such as:

```
[50, 178] top left
[50, -178] top right
[-50, -178] bottom right
[-50, 178] bottom left
```

This is the data provided when pulled out from looping the polygon.getPath() points.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {
polySelected = true;
coords = new Array();
polygon.getPath().forEach(function (l, index) {
coords[index]="("+l.lat()+","+l.lng()+")"
});
}
```

With this data, it is impossible to tell if the points actually cross the 180 meridian line. If I took out the 'upper left', 'upper right', you would have no way of discerning if the users second point was to the right (crossing 180) or left (making a very large box).

Is there any way around this? Such as not having 'wrapped' coordinates [50, **182**] like that? What is the standard way of dealing with crossing the boundaries and having data representing that?

Thanks!

**Edit** - This is not a case of closing the polygon and having coordinates snap to a very large area. This case is for a normal polygon manual closure, creating a small square polygon, but one that crosses the map horizontal repeat and having the resultant coordinates be indistinguishable from a polygon that crosses the repeat 180 meridian line, or one that is very wide (but no different vertically) and covering the opposite area. I wish I could demonstrate with pictures to help explain but I do not have this functionality yet.

**Answer**
I do not see a way to answer my own question, however I have figured it out and want to share. I realized that you cannot draw an edge of a polygon that extends more than 180 degrees longitudinally. Knowing that, if you have two points that have a different of greater than 180, it crosses the +/-180 meridian.

Thanks to all who were offering support!

Comment: The [google.maps.LatLng class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) supports an optional noWrap argument.  Polygons tend to go the shortest path, even if it crossed the meridian, if you want them to go the long way, you need to insert additional vertices.

Comment: Thanks, I did notice this, however I am using google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager which creates the polygon and I have not seen a way to implement that to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var longitude = l.lng();
while (longitude > 180)
    longitude -= 360; // e.g. 182 and 542 become -178, which is the equivalent longitude
while (longitude < -180)
    longitude += 360;

coords[index]="("+l.lat()+","+longitude+")";
```

As long as your latitude is between 90 and -90. If it isn't you need to fix that too... let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: You really don't want to wrap latitude the same way as longitude...  In any case I don't think this is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Geo: why not for latitude? it goes from -90 to 90, and latitude 92 is like -88 latitude no? And what do you think the OP is looking for if not this?

Comment: 92 degrees is north of the north pole, -88 degrees is just north of the south pole, they are nowhere near each other, while -181 degrees and +179 degrees of latitude are the same place.

Comment: Ah, you're right. You can't use the same technique for latitude.

Comment: Hi, I looked at the other solution presented however I do not think this applies to my question. Longitude never goes beyond 180 which is part of my problem. I would like coordinates to stretch beyond, so I can distinguish that my polygon is actually a small polygon just over the 180 mark, rather than a giant polygon that extends over most of the map and not the 180 meridian.